# How to wrap buttons in div those are switching between divs?

Tags: html, css, button

I have this source code. It's supposed to switch between tabs after clicking on any of the buttons. Everything works fine but when I try to wrap buttons in div it stops working and it doesnt display content anymore.

```css
.main {
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-width: 320px;
  max-width: 800px;
}

.content {
  background: #fff;
  color: #373737;
}

.content>div {
  display: none;
  padding: 20px 25px 5px;
}

input {
  display: none;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
}

label:hover {
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input:checked+label {
  background: #ed5a6a;
  color: #fff;
}

#tab1:checked~.content #content1,
#tab2:checked~.content #content2,
#tab3:checked~.content #content3,
#tab4:checked~.content #content4 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <input id="tab1" type="radio" name="tabs" checked>
  <label for="tab1">111</label>

  <input id="tab2" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab2">222</label>

  <input id="tab3" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab3">333</label>

  <input id="tab4" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab4">444</label>

  <div class="content">
    <div id="content1">
      <p>
        111
      </p>
    </div>

    <div id="content2">
      <p>
        222
      </p>
    </div>

    <div id="content3">
      <p>
        333
      </p>
    </div>

    <div id="content4">
      <p>
        444
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The code above is working, but I would like to wrap this part in `div`:

```html
<input id="tab1" type="radio" name="tabs" checked>
<label for="tab1">111</label>

<input id="tab2" type="radio" name="tabs">
<label for="tab2">222</label>

<input id="tab3" type="radio" name="tabs">
<label for="tab3">333</label>

<input id="tab4" type="radio" name="tabs">
<label for="tab4">444</label>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are changing the document structure and this selector:

```
#tab1:checked ~ .content #content1,
#tab2:checked ~ .content #content2,
#tab3:checked ~ .content #content3,
#tab4:checked ~ .content #content4 {
  display: block;
}
```

no longer matches the content areas. I can't think of a selector that would work because the addition of the new `div` breaks the sibling relationship between the tabs and the content.

However, you can add your `div` and make the code much simpler if you abandon the hidden radio buttons and the labels and just use `a` elements that target the content area that is supposed to be displayed. Then the CSS **[`:target` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target)** can be used to display the current content area that is the target of the clicked link.

Additionally, it's not clear why you have the actual content in a `p` that is inside of the `div`. That doesn't seem necessary.

```html
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <style>
      .main {margin: 0 auto; min-width: 320px; max-width: 800px;}
      .content {background: #fff; color: #373737;}
      .content > div {display: none; padding: 20px 25px 5px;}
      a {display: inline-block; padding: 15px 25px; font-weight: 600; text-align: center;}
      a:hover {color: #fff; cursor: pointer;}
      a:link {background: #ed5a6a; color: #fff; text-decoration:none; }
      .content > :target
       {
        display: block;
      } 
      </style>
     </head>
     <body>
      <div class="main">
          <div id="parent">
          <a href="#content1" id="tab1">111</a>
          <a href="#content2" id="tab1">222</a>
            <a href="#content3" id="tab1">333</a>
          <a href="#content4" id="tab1">444</a>            
                        
         </div>
        <div class="content">  
         <div id="content1">111</div>
         <div id="content2">222</div>
         <div id="content3">333</div>
         <div id="content4">444</div>
        </div>
     
      </div>
     </body>
    </html>
```